# Post Without Validating

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

My form has a reset button that returns a shiny new View. However, all of the fields which are invalid at the time the reset button is pressed show their corresponding validation messages for a split second before the page refreshes with the new View. It looks unprofessional.

**On the client side (in JavaScript), how do I post and disregard validation?**

If my user intends to reset the form, I do not want to flash red validation messages at him. I am using typical MVC Data Annotations like the following in my Model.

```
[Display(Name="IP Address")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public string address { get; set; }
```

Here is a relevant portion of my View. All of the form fields are declared in similar fashion.

```
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.address):
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.address)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.address, String.Empty, new { @class ="errorMessage"})
</p>
```

Finally, here is the Javascript that runs when the reset button is clicked. I think that submit() is what causes all of the validation messages to appear, but I do not sure how to post any other way.

```
$('#resetButton').click(function () {
    this.form.submit();
});
```

My attempts to Google "*javascript POST without validating*" keeps finding pages like "*validate without post*", and if you try the phrase "*POST without validating*" in quotes you get almost nothing useful.

Comment: Is there a good reason to reload the page in order to reload the form?    `$('#resetButton').click(function () {
    this.form.reset();
});`

Comment: You are a lifesaver. It looks like `this.form.reset();` does NOT trigger validation. If you make your answer an answer I will mark it as such. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't submit a `POST` at all; reset the form in place.  Use the DOM (non-jquery) form reset function:

```
$('#resetButton').click(function () {
  this.form.reset();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

attibute and assign it to your controller's action if you are sure that this action will not require any validation.

The question is whether you really need to make a post call, when you only need to reset your form (so no  server action is needed). In case it is just about resetting the form you could use the following:

```
$('#resetButton').click(function () { 
    this.form.reset(); 
});
```

Instead of:

```
$('#resetButton').click(function () {
    this.form.submit();
});
```

Comment: Where do you add that tag? I tried putting it in front of my controller like `[HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Index(MyModel newData, string submitButton, string resetButton)` and the validation messages still flash before the page reloads.

Comment: But why do you exactly need to make a post call? Can't you just reset the form using form.reset() method?

Comment: Second person to mention that (see comments on Question) but nobody has actually made it an answer, so I can't give anyone the check.